# MySQL "no database selected"

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am using the following code to connect to my database. I get a no database selected error.

```
    require '../dbconnect.php';

session_start();

$username_input = $_POST['username_input'];
$password_input = $_POST['password_input'];

$sql = "SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM users WHERE username = '$username_input' LIMIT 0, 30";
$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);

printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbcon));
exit();

    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $user_number = $row[0];
    $username = $row[1];
    $password = $row[2];
    $salt = $row[3];
```

I know similar questions have been asked in the past, but looking through those, I could not find my problem.

Comment: Your issue lays in `dbconnect.php`. You probably haven't run `mysqli_select_db()` or supplied the db param to `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: can also be solved with .. `FROM DB_NAME.users` ..

Comment: Please provide code in your `dbconnect.php`. Make sure to strip away sensitive information like hostnames, usernames, ans passwords.

Comment: check the require path.....may be your path is not absolute

Comment: @Krumia It's just running on my computer. No danger there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using one single database most of the time, it's better to supply your database name in your `mysql_connect` as follows:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("hostname_or_ip","user","passw","db_name") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: I added the database name as the last argument in mysqli_connect and it works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to query MySQL without selecting a database. To fix this you need to specify which DB your are connecting to by using the USE statement before executing any queries.

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, 'USE mydatabase');
```

Comment: @Marcel: What "Error" do you get? Please add that information to your question.

Comment: @Krumia I got a blank error. The only thing on the page was "Error:".